# Can I persist the state of user input to AMP form upon email reload?

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

Say I have an AMP form embedded within a dynamic gmail. Is there a way to persist the state and show what the users inputted upon reload of the email without utilizing an amp-list component fetching data from another endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

No. Access to any sort of local storage (cookies, `localStorage`, IndexedDB, etc.) are strictly prohibited for security reasons.